# How to export private images from Drupal

Tags: media, database

I want to export private images from Drupal to an external client. How to I authenticate an external client to access private files from Drupal DB?

Comment: Could you expand on the 'secure' requirement? With your files being stored at publicly accessible URLs I'm not sure what concerns you'd have there

Comment: Ok, tried to change it. If you have any suggestions how to change body to a more Drupal question I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [file_create_url($uri)](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_create_url/7) to create an externally accessible url for the file.

If used with private file mode files, you will need to implement hook_file_download

You might also be interested in the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module, to expose an API for the files, which can provide authentication methods such as Drupal session and OAuth authentication.